# why yii2 view are not being affected by css

Tags: php, css, yii2

my yii2 view/site/index is ok and my css is working there fine, however, other pages, for example view/about and view/login are just html without css and working terrible, what could be causing it?  why my css is only working in view/index ?

Comment: can you tell us where you included your css? and share your code and tell us which file it is in?

Comment: May I suggest checking the page source and making sure that the pathes to the css and js files are correct? Can you show us how you are including the css and js files in your project?

Comment: thank you friends for helping me, actually the problem was fixed and it was because of wrong configuration of web.php and htacess